# how to show detail log fastapi Invalid HTTP Request received?

Tags: python, logging, fastapi, uvicorn

I have simple webserver with fastapi, but I got `WARNING:  Invalid HTTP request received.` is there any way to show detail log of that?

maybe like the ip, or the path, or the time, I want more detail, instead `Invalid HTTP request received`

[image: error invalid http request received]

my pip version:

fastapi: 0.92.0

uvicorn: 0.20.0